# Use undeclared type of CVCalendarView

Tags: ios, swift3

https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar#basic-setup

I am using CVCalendarView with CocoaPods. I am successfully implementing views for that procedure but it shows

> Use undeclared type of CVCalendarView

as shown in images[image]

The CocaPods file is shown in below

[image]

but in storyboard I am successfully subclassing view

[image]

target member ship
[image]

IMPORTING IMAGE[image]

Comment: it showing no such module

Comment: Hmm I see. Another question for you, what file did you open after installing the pods ? .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace ?

Comment: .xcworkspace  file

Comment: I wrote an answer for you, just let me know if it works! :)

Comment: try to de-intetgrate the pods clean the project and then hit pod install again.

Comment: can u tell me the procedure to de - integrate

Comment: pod deintegrate and pod clean are two designated commands to remove CocoaPod from your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go back to your podfile, and instead of `pod 'CVCalendar', '~> 1.5.2'`, just type:

`pod 'CVCalendar'`

And press CMD+S to save the changes.

Then in the Terminal just go to your folder where you have your project using `cd`, for instance:

```
cd /Desktop/yourProjectFolder
```

*Note: If your project is not on your Desktop, you may want to adjust the line above.*

Once you're in your project directory type:

```
pod install
```

After installing the pods in your podfile, open up the `.xcworkspace` file that was created.

Finally, add the import statement at the top of your file :

```
import CVCalendar
```

And now, hopefully, everything should work just fine!

Just try this and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: could you please show me your logs when you install the pods ?

Comment: in pod folder it showing debugging and releasing files is it fine?

Comment: Macwins-MacBook-Pro:GMHospitalUiFinal macwin$ cd "/Users/macwin/Documents/GMHospitalUiFinal"
Macwins-MacBook-Pro:GMHospitalUiFinal macwin$ open -a Xcode Podfile
Macwins-MacBook-Pro:GMHospitalUiFinal macwin$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using CVCalendar (1.5.2)
Installing JTAppleCalendar (7.0.6)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.
Macwins-MacBook-Pro:GMHospitalUiFinal macwin$

Comment: Hmm that's really weird, everything seems to be fine though.

Comment: One more thing that you could try is, open up Xcode, and in the top bar menu click on "Xcode" > "Preferences". Then open the "Locations" tab.

Comment: In the Locations tab, click on the little arrow that points to the right, it will open your Xcode folder and you will see a folder called DerivedData. Just remove it, and go back to Xcode and press CMD + SHIFT + K to clean your project. Now quit your project completely, and try opening again your xcworkspace file

Comment: After doing all that, try again adding import CVCalendar at the top (outside from the class brackets) and let me know if it works

Comment: at the first time it sucessfully importing and after few seconds it showing no such module

Comment: Are you sure it was the DerivedData folder ? It's very unlikely to be empty though.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what is going on here :e I just checked it out on my computer now, and it works just fine.

Comment: target member ship for cvccalender ?

Comment: You're adding the import statement at the top of your ViewController.swift (or whatever name it is) file right ?

Comment: Is the target membership properly set in your project ? I run out of ideas here :S

Comment: Hmm okay. Please show me a screenshot of the top of your file where you're adding the import statement, and declaring the @IBOutlets etc.

Comment: I HAVE UPDATED PLEASE CHECK IT

Comment: Why uppercases?